# Probability and probability amplitude

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, statistics, probability, complex-numbers

What made scientists believe that we should calculate probability $P$ as the $P = \left|\psi\right|^2$ in quantum mechanics? Was it the double slit experiment? How? Is there anywhere in the statistical mathematics a similar equation where we calculate probability like $P=\left|x\right|^2$ where $x$ is whatever?

Comment: "[F]or a detailed reconstruction of the historical origin of the Born rule within the context
of quantum mechanics," see: J. Mehra and H. Rechenberg, The Historical Development of Quantum Theory. Vol. 6: The Completion of
Quantum Mechanics 1926–1941. Part 1: The Probabilistic Interpretation and the Empirical and Mathematical Foundation of Quantum Mechanics, 1926-1936, Springer-Verlag, New York, 2000. [Source.](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/4012/1/MBorn.pdf)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the historical origin was, but the [Stern-Gerlach experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment) and particularly variations with multiple Stern-Gerlach filters can teach us a lot about probabilities in QM. I might write up a more detailed answer in the future but at the moment I don't really have the time.

Comment: Earlier, related question by the same poster: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51962/